# How to download files from Wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress, google-cloud-platform, download

So I built a wordpress website with an online builder and hosted on a Google Cloud VirtualMachine. Is there any way I can download all the files so I can run it locally on my PC? I am interested in the .HTML and .PHP files, the media doesn't really matter. Thank you!

Comment: Have a look at the documentation [Moving WordPress](https://wordpress.org/support/article/moving-wordpress/). You should create backup of your data and database if you want to be able to run copy of your site at home. Then you should download backups to your local machine. Which OS do you use at home?

Comment: You also might be able to sftp into the cloud machine and download all the files like that, depending on what type of virtual machine this is

Answer (score 0):

You can download Wordpress for free from https://wordpress.org/download/

That will contain all the html and php files your website currently uses.

If you are using a custom theme then you will need to download that separately and install it.

If you want to run Wordpress locally then you will need a local web server such as https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html or https://localwp.com/